# How to send custom tcp packets on windows?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, winpcap

I want to send a packets which I define the ip address, port, data, .etc, at first I thought maybe I can use raw sockets on windows, but after googling for a while, I found that it seemed ms has disabled raw sockets from XP SP2 (is it really?), now I don't know how to do. Someone tells me to use winPcap, then I go to the home page of that software, only to find the last version of that software was released on 02 jul 10, which is too old, I dont know whether it still works now. If possible, I preferred to use Python to complete the task, but it seems inconvenient to use python to realize the `raw socket`, now I don't know how to do it. Does anyone have a good idea about it? any help appreciated.

Comment: And does socket.socket not fit your need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.sendto('\xff'*6 + '\x00\x50\xe4\x59\xd9\x30'*16, ('168.1.0.0', 4444))
```

The documentation for the `socket` module reads ([last example](http://file://localhost/opt/local/share/doc/python27-doc/library/socket.html#example)) "The example requires administrator privileges to modify the interface", so you might want to check out how to do this.

Comment: thx a lot, but i mean that i want to send to the specific ip address using specific port, IOW i want to camouflage an application to send the packets

Comment: Yeah, but someone said that codes Raw socket using python may not be as convenient as C, so i am considering which language should i use, and just as what i have said above, it seems that ms has disabled raw socket from XP SP2, so i dont know whether it does work now. have you ever used `socket.SOCK_RAW` before? @Kimvais

Answer (score 1):

[scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows) should let you do this.

Answer (score 0):

This works at least on Win7 when the python is run as administrator:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.sendto(b"\x00"*16, (192.168.0.255, 0)
```

Comment: can you give a more detail example? e.g. i want to edit each part of that packet, can python realize it?