# Is it possible to use Scapy to send a raw TCP packet on Windows?

Tags: windows, tcp, scapy, raw-sockets

[Windows usually blocks sending raw IP packets with app-specied TCP payloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281097/why-am-i-getting-an-exception-on-windows-8-using-raw-sockets-with-ipproto-tcp).  I would like to be able to do this because it would allow students to use Python's beautiful sockets library to send TCP packets without having to resort to dual booting or running a VM or using WSL (if either of those even works under Windows).

Looking though the Scapy documentation and Stack overflow posts, it appears Scapy can send packets, but it always seems to do so through the native socket library.  Or is it overriding the socket library when we import it?

It appears this [may have been possible on Windows 7 even without Scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515525/how-to-send-custom-tcp-packets-on-windows), but I'm sure it's not possible without something like Scapy today.

I've seen several questions mention using Scapy to work with raw packets, with one question mentioning that Scapy works through npcap (or something similar) on Windows, and the [Scapy documentiation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) mentions that Scapy can send packets.

[It appears Scapy able to work around the raw packet limitations on Windows by sending packets through libpcap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73757285/how-do-libraries-like-scapy-npcap-winpcap-etc-get-around-windows-limitatio), but how can we do this through simple Python code?